# Formulário de registro e login no Wordpress com woocomerce

Tags: wordpress

Formulário de registro e login no Wordpress 4.7 com woocomerce 2.6.11 não funciona com o tema Bookshelf | Books & Media Online Store.

Obs.: O cadastro do cliente dando acesso a sua área restrita só ocorre apos conclusão de um pedido mas, após logout o mesmo não consegue acessar sua área restrita através do menu Login.

Answer (score 1):

Nem todos os temas do WP são compatíveis com woocommerce e alguns dos que são, tem de ser configurados/estruturados para funcionar corretamente.

As vezes, quando mudamos o tema, a estrutura do site é alterada pelas config. padrão do novo tema.

Se puder, troque para um tema padrão (tipo storefront) e veja se o site funciona e está completo. Então poderá comparar os dois.

Comment: Obrigado Rene mas, o template funciona perfeitamente no site de demonstração com a plataforma wordpress 4.5.4 e woocommerce 2.6.1.